# Drawing to a created Bitmap from onDraw()

Tags: android, bitmap, ondraw

I'm trying to draw to a Bitmap so I can put my custom view inside an imageView.The code within the onDraw method is:

```
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {     

    Bitmap drawGraph = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);       
    canvas.setBitmap(drawGraph);    
    canvas.drawBitmap(drawGraph, 0, 0, bgPaint);
```

My problem is that if I try to use a Bitmap in this way, I just get a black screen. I know that the rest of my code works as it displays if I don't try to draw to a bitmap.

If I comment out the line

```
canvas.setBitmap(drawGraph);
```

Then everything works perfectly, so this is the problem but I dont know why.

where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're going wrong by not explaining what your problem actually is, or what's not working.

Comment: Fair point! I've edited the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I did have to create a second canvas. My working code is below just for anyone who might need it:

```
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Canvas singleUseCanvas = new Canvas();      

    drawGraph = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);      
    singleUseCanvas.setBitmap(drawGraph);   

    canvas.drawBitmap(drawGraph, 100, 100, bgPaint);
```

Comment: onDraw can be called anywhere from 1 to 15 times. Putting `Bitmap.createBitmap` inside of `onDraw` will lead to OutOfMemory errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think is the `canvas` and `canvas2` dichotomy. Try to use only canvas2 (the parameter) to draw.

Comment: I did originally, and have since changed it back to that but to no avail. Surely this should work:                     Bitmap drawGraph = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
  canvas.setBitmap(drawGraph);

Comment: I don't undesrtand you. If the code has changed, please update your question. But again, you shouldn't create a new Canvas, just draw on the one it is passed as param.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK The most efficient way is to override drawable setters.

```
@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    bmp = bm;
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    try {
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    } catch (Exception e){
        log(e.toString());
    }
}
```