# Android Save Canvas into Bitmap

Tags: android

I have been struggling on converting a Canvas to a Bitmap. 
Here is my code on the onDraw function. I have tried many variations and I still didn't get an answer.

```
    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    for(List<Point> pointA : pointWhole)
    {
        Point prev = null;
        for (Point point : pointA) {
            if(prev != null)
            {
                canvas.drawLine(prev.x, prev.y, point.x, point.y, paint);
            }
            prev = point;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to save the whole bitmap.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828595/drawing-to-a-created-bitmap-from-ondraw

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Save The Image From Canvas code in Android Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442610/how-to-save-the-image-from-canvas-code-in-android-application)

Comment: @Sameer: If you think a question is a duplicate then voting to close it is sufficient. Editing the question body to include a faux "duplicate" link is really not appropriate.