# How to save a canvas into a bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, ondraw

I'm trying to save a background from a ViewPagerParallax which can be found here : [link](https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/ViewPagerParallax)

When i move, the background changes, and i want to take this "part" of the background and pass it to another activity.

To pass it from one to another activty i can :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //Bitmap bmp = pager.getSavedBitmap().getBitmap();
            Bitmap bmp = pager.getBitmap();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            intent.putExtra("image",byteArray);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

---

```
    byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
    layout.setBackground(d);
```

But know to take the part of the background i want is difficult, i'm trying to take it from the onDraw method like this :

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(saved_bitmap, src, dst, null);
        if(canvas != null){         
            my_bitmap = new BitmapDrawable();
            my_bitmap.draw(canvas);
        }
```

But when i use getBitmap :

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(){
    return my_bitmap.getBitmap();
}
```

the image is not scaled like it was in the first activity.

Comment: Just a suggestion, do no use Strong references for Bitmaps use `WeakReference<Bitmap>`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this post have a similar issue? [Android Save Canvas into Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515674/android-save-canvas-into-bitmap)

Perhaps it might help.